# How to check if $f(x)=x^2\sin(x)^{-1}$ is differentiable at 0?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would I check if $f(x)=x^2\sin(x)^{-1}$ is differentiable at 0?

I tried using the definition of a derivative but got stuck at the limit part. Does one care what happens **at** the limit point, or only what happens near it?

\begin{align}
f^\prime(0) &= \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\\
&= \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^2\sin(x)^{-1}-0}{x-0}\\
&= \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x}{\sin(x)}\\
&=1? \text{ or does it not exist?} 
\end{align}

Comment: @TedShifrin I thought he was referring to  $\frac{x^2}{\sin x}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I agree it is an uncorrect way to write that but from the derivation presented it seems to be intepreted as $\frac{x^2}{\sin x}$. Indeed I've used that notation to indicate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\to 0} x\cdot \frac{x}{\sin x} =0 $$

and since $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$ we need to define $f(0)=0$ to make it countinuous at that point. Then, as you have shown, since by the definition the limit exists, $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a simple *Taylor expansion* works well:

When $x$ approches $0$, $\frac{x}{\sin(x)} = \frac{x}{x - \frac{x^3}{6}+\text{o}(x^3)} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{x^2}{6}+\text{o}(x^2)} \rightarrow 1$.

So, yeah

$
\begin{align}
f^\prime(0) &= \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x}{\sin(x)} =1.
\end{align}
$